# Visualforce - Clickable DataTable Cells - How to get Column and Row information

Tags: datatable, click, visualforce

I'd like to create a datatable where each cell is clickable.  I'm assuming that I can probably fill each cell with `apex:outputlink` and that takes care of the clickable part as well as calling my controller for each click.  The big question I need an answer for is how do I pass information to my apex controller about which cell (i.e.: which row and which column) was actually clicked.

Any help for this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Its easy. Just define an action function to catch the values from the dataTable:

1) First defining three vars tht we will pass to controller: raw-id, cell-value, cell-type

```java
public String clickedRowId { get; set; } 
public String clickedCellValue { get; set; } 
public String clickedCellType { get; set; } 

public PageReference readCellMethod(){
    System.debug('#### clickedRowId: ' + clickedRowId);
    System.debug('#### clickedCellValue: ' + clickedCellValue);
    System.debug('#### clickedCellType: ' + clickedCellType);
    return null;
}
```

2) Second we create an action function, that calls our apex method an pass three vars to it:

```salesforce
<apex:actionFunction name="readCell" action="{!readCellMethod}">
    <apex:param name="P1" value="" assignTo="{!clickedRowId}"/>
    <apex:param name="P2" value="" assignTo="{!clickedCellValue}"/>
    <apex:param name="P3" value="" assignTo="{!clickedCellType}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

3) And third we create our dataTable, where each cell has onClick listener:

```salesforce
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!someArray}" var="item">

    <apex:column value="{!item.name}" onclick="readCell('{!item.id}','{!item.name}','name')" />
    <apex:column value="{!item.CustomField1__c}" onclick="readCell('{!item.id}','{!item.CustomField1__c}','custom1')" />
    <apex:column value="{!item.CustomField2__c}" onclick="readCell('{!item.id}','{!item.CustomField2__c}','custom2')" />

</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

We can access our actionFunction like any other JavaScript function. If user clicks on the cell - three vars will be send to the actionFunction and then to controller.